# SAPUI5 Association between 2 entities in the backend system?

Tags: javascript, calendar, odata, sapui5

I have 2 Entity sets

First one

[image]

and the second one

[image]

The red marked data in the first one are the same data as in the second one with blue marks.

I need the red one in the second pictures. So for example I got in this picture the entityset from the first picture of metadata there is `Personalnummer`, `Mvorname`, `Mnachname`. It should stay always Static.

***Info***: I got a calendar, when I click I want to change the `Dauer` for the Person for the day which I clicked. So thats why the other one stay static and only the `Dauer` is dynamic based on the day I click

The `Dauer` should came from the second picture of Metadata and the `Pernr = PernrMitarbeiter`, `Vorname = Mvorname` and `Nachname = Mnachname`

Is there a way to connect it with a Filter which is based on the `Workdate`?

So like get the data from the first one and check it with the second entity and than put the `Dauer` into the fields?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the OData definition, create an association from `ZOOWVM` to `ZOOWVTU_S` - let’s call it `duration` - with cardinality 1:0..1 over the three foreign key fields. Then you can access the second entity via links of the form `/ZOOWVMs(PernrMeister=‘a’,Auftrag=‘b’,PernrMitarbeiter=‘c’)/duration`.

I do hope these names are scrambled for privacy’s sake. If they aren’t, you should really consider giving your entities and properties properly readable names.

Comment: Hmm, but i cant Filter After workdate for Dauer ? My Main problem is, im just learning all this .. and i just Want to have the Vorname and Nachname Static, it should stay  and dont change.. but Dauer should be Dynamic like i press on the 25.01 the Dauer for the day should change for the Person.. Thats Why i set it in 2 different entitys .. behause When all is in One i Need to Filter After the workdate and MeisterNr, and i Need for every day some  entrys (for the Future Date).Thats i dont want i want that the names stay Static for ever and only the Dauer should change. Thanks for the tips :))

Comment: You can also filter along associations, for example /ZOOWVMs(PernrMeister=‘a’,Auftrag=‘b’,PernrMitarbeiter=‘c’)/duration?$filter=duration/Workdate=‘29-01-2019’.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. i found a other way because the associations thing ive never done really.. for the people: I made a array in the array the data from one entity and done a second array from the other entity.. than i compare it and get the getAggregation("cells")[0].getText() compare it with my second array and than set the text